# Automated creation of a new environment in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I could not find a definite 'yes' or 'no' anywhere, so I thought maybe I ask here. Is it possible to run a custom script which would automatically create a new environment on AWS with all the settings like (Network, Capacity, Security etc.)? I need to create a lot of new environments as I am switching from individual load balancers to shared ones, and all the settings are the same (apart from the environment and application name), so it involves a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [What is AWS CloudFormation? - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html):

> AWS CloudFormation is a service that helps you model and set up your AWS resources so that you can spend less time managing those resources and more time focusing on your applications that run in AWS. You create a template that describes all the AWS resources that you want (like Amazon EC2 instances or Amazon RDS DB instances), and CloudFormation takes care of provisioning and configuring those resources for you. You don't need to individually create and configure AWS resources and figure out what's dependent on what; CloudFormation handles that.

If you want to create the CloudFormation template **programmatically**, you can use [AWS CDK - AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/home.html):

> The AWS CDK lets you build reliable, scalable, cost-effective applications in the cloud with the considerable expressive power of a programming language.
>
> The AWS CDK supports TypeScript, JavaScript, Python, Java, C#/.Net, and Go. Developers can use one of these supported programming languages to define reusable cloud components known as Constructs. You compose these together into Stacks and Apps.

Or, you can simply write your own script in a programming language that calls an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to individually create resources in AWS. Everything in AWS can be done via API calls.